# Visual Studio Code Multiline select

Tags: ide, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

VS studio's shortcut is `Alt+Click`. But my Alt button doesnt work
How can i switch that shortcut to Ctrl+Click?
I didnt find that shortcut in settings, maybe there is one more way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to reconfigure this, though it was being discussed on this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3091).

However, there are other ways to add multiple cursors (which is what alt+click does in Visual Studio Code), though they aren't exactly what you are looking for. These are the default keybindings for the commands that add cursors:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+up",           "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAbove",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+i",           "command": "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+down",         "command": "editor.action.insertCursorBelow",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```

Comment: all of them are using `Alt` button which is broken on my keyboard)

Comment: Those can be remapped to any key combination you want.